# Pegando um nova informação de um site e adicionar uma nova linha com essa informação a todo momento que é atualizado

Tags: api, listview, flutter, app

ola pessoal estou tentando pegar dados de um site api(servidor próprio) e assim mostrar o novo dado no aplicativo assim que o site fizer um update com novas informações, assim adicionando uma linha nova e mantendo os dados antigos, tentei usar o `listview`, mas não consegui pois só aparece a linha nova e as outras desaparecem.

```
if (snapshot.data != null && snapshot.data != oldSnapshot) {
                        oldSnapshot = snapshot.data;
                        return ListView.separated(itemBuilder: (_, index) => Text('Volta :' +
                              snapshot.data.lap.toString() +
                              ' Velocidade :' +
                              snapshot.data.vel.toString() +
                              ' Tempo :' +
                              snapshot.data.datetime.toString()),
                               separatorBuilder: (_, int i) => Divider(), 
                               itemCount: 28,
                               controller: controller,
                          );
```

Comment: Mostre mais do seu código, apenas com essa parte não podemos te ajudar em muita coisa... Como você está pegando os dados da API? A API utiliza SocketIO ou algo do tipo para que você fique escutando as mudanças em tempo real? A sua API retorna registro por registro ou todos de uma vez?  *[Edita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/460331/edit)* a sua pergunta e nos dê mais informações cara.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vejo no seu código você está atualizando a `ListView` com o valor que você acabou de receber, pelo modo em que você colocou o código eu presumo que você esteja usando o `StreamBuilder` que irá reconstruir a sua lista a cada vez que você recebe uma nova linha do server. Não existe um metódo para adicionar linhas a uma `ListView`, a cada vêz que o valor atualizar ela irá mostrar o valor atual da sua lista e não irá manter nenhum referimento aos valores antigos, possíveis soluções para o seu problema:

1. Use um StatefulWidget

Este seria o seu metódo `build`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Evite fazer operações complexas dentro do metodo build, visto que o mesmo pode e será chamado
    /// várias vezes enquanto a sua página estiver aberta, e em cada chamada toda a sua 
    /// lógica será reprocessada
    return ListView.separated(
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => lista[index],
      separatorBuilder: (_, int i) => Divider(), 
      itemCount: 28,
      controller: controller,
    );
  }
```

Como você pode notar o metódo `build` se ocupa simplesmente de criar e mostrar a lista, a lógica necessária você pode definir dentro ao metódo `initState`

```
List<String> lista = List();
StreamSubscription<String> subscription;

@override
initState(){
  /// Suponho que de qualquer forma o seu script que recebe tais informações
  /// do server tenha uma stream onde ele emite os valores recebidos pelo server
  myServerAPI.listen((data) {
    /// Dê preferência por ultilizar a interpolação, é mais legível
    final line = 'Volta: ${data.lap.toString()} Velocidade ${data.vel.toString()} Tempo: ${data.datetime.toString()}';

    /// Atualize o state do seu Widget
    setState(() {
      /// Adicione a nova linha a sua lista
      lista.add(line);
    });
  })
}
```

Não se esqueça de cancelar a `subscription` uma vez que não é mais necessária, você pode fazer isso quando o seu Widget será destruído por exemplo:

```
@override
dispose(){
  subscription.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Dica: Sua resposta pode estar correta pro caso dele, mas não tente usar sua bola de cristal sempre, se não vai sempre ficar aparecendo perguntas cada vez mais rasas e sem informações necessárias...